# HSPICE - Probing Current of an Element Defined By SUBCKT

Tags: hspice

For a regular resistor model, to plot I-V curve, I write: 
`R1 m0 m1 1`
`.probe DC i(R1)` 
Then, I open CSCOPE. i(R1) is listed. By selecting it, I can see its I-V behavior.

Now, I have a device that is defined with `.subckt`: 
`.subckt device m0 m1 param=p` 
Then, I instantiate it and probe it by: 
`x1 m0 m1 device`
`.probe DC i(X1)`
However, when I open CSCOPE, i(x1) is not listed, so I cannot see the diagram. 
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: I don't know HSPICE, but, for example, in LTspice, there's an option in the settings, to save, or not, subcircuit voltages and currents (checkboxes). Maybe there's something similar in HSPICE?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, thanks for your response. I don't work with the GUI, so don't know about that. There may be a command for it. I came up with a solution, I connected a resistor with 0 value in series with my device, and plotted its current.

Comment: Oh, I thought you want the current *inside* the subcircuit. Well, ma' bad. I'll post an answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: Try .PROBE DC ISUB(X1.port) where port is the name of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current through a block defined by a subcircuit, then the current is defined as `Ix`, followed by the part's designator, a colon, and the pin as defined internally.

For example:

```
.subckt xxx 1 2
R1 1 2 1
.ends xxx
```

This subcircuit is a simple resistor, and its pins are named `1` and `2`. But the *symbol* that uses this subcircuit can have its pins named differently.

If they are named `A` and `B`, and if the designator is `U1`, then the current through pin `1` would be: `Ix(U1:A)`.

If the pins are named similarly, `1` and `2`, and the same designator, then the current would be `Ix(U1:1)`.

If the designator would be `SpecialPart13`, and the pins similarly named, then the current would be `Ix(SpecialPart:1)`.

If you look at the netlist, the block is defined as `X1 ...`, that is the `x` in `Ix`. If you would work with a GUI and you would see `U1`, most likely the netlist will show `XU1 ...`.

So, for your case, if the netlist shows `X1`, and the pin is named `1`, then the current through that pin would be `Ix(1:1)`. If the name of the pin is `IN`, then it's `Ix(1:IN)`.